# I can't consume microservice Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, microservices, axios

I'm learning java Spring and I want to consume one microservice so I created a form in HTML and I try to send the user and password with axios

```
var helloWorld = new Vue({
el: '#vue-app',
    data: 
{
    user: "user",
    username : "",
    password : ""
},
methods: 
{
    enviar: function()
    {
         axios.post('/user/login', {
             user: this.username,
             password: this.password
         })
         .then(function (response) {
             console.log(response);
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
    }
}

});
```

and I try to get the information

```
@Controller("/user")
public class UserController {

private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserController.class);

@PostMapping("/login")
public boolean login(@RequestParam("user") String user, @RequestParam("password") String password)
{
    log.info("user: " + user + " password: " + password);
    return user.equals("hitzu") && password.equals("250693");

}
}`
```

But when I try to run the code I get error 404 and I try to set the URL in Postman

http://localhost:8080/user/login?user=hitzu&password=250693

but get the same error.

Comment: Check if the package in which the UserController is getting scanned.

Comment: Is that normal to have an HTML link with a username and password in it like that?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting 404 because your controller thinks it should bind a View with the data it fetches.

Tell it not to bind a View essentially making it a REST endpoint and directly write into the HTTP Response Body by annotating your method with **@ResponseBody**.

[Some further info on @ResponseBody from the Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-responsebody)